# Aligned data in ListPicker

Tags: grid-layouts

Considering some data:

```
data = {{DateObject[{2015, 7, 9}], "81st", 10.5187}, 
  {DateObject[{2015, 7, 10}], "81st", 11.0627}, 
  {DateObject[{2015, 7, 13}], "81st", 10.6428}, 
  {DateObject[{2015, 7, 13}], "71st", 21.5}};
```

It's not hard to use `Grid` to present the data in tabular format where it is easily digested.

```
Framed@Pane[
 Style[
  Grid[(data /. x_ /; DateObjectQ[x] :> 
   DateString[x, {"MonthShort", "/", "DayShort", "/", "Year"}]), 
Frame -> All], 18, FontFamily -> "Calibri"], 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}, Scrollbars -> {False, True}]
```

[image]

Coupling with `Dynamic` it would be nice to be able to select certain rows of data for later use, either deletion or amending or whatever. Conveniently, we have `ListPicker`:

```
ListPicker[Dynamic[pos], 
 Thread[Range[Length[data]] -> Map[Row[#, " - "] &, data]]]
```

[image]

What I'd like to be able to do is have the data in each element (ie row) of `ListPicker` to be aligned as it would be in the above `Grid` example.

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

As I was typing the question, I thought of a way by adding a level to `data`. As the question was already typed, I just decided to answer my own question, hoping that someone else has an easier way. This method also restricts all column widths to be the same.

```
ListPicker[Dynamic[pos], 
 Thread[Range[Length[data]] -> 
 Map[Grid[{#}, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> 15] &, data]]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Kuba Good catch. I originally had it as the `Map[]` form, but changed it to infix when I was cleaning it up to post here. I switched it back and it works as I originally intended.